# Why do CSS animations not work in Angular components in Safari?

Tags: css, angular, animation, safari

CSS animations work fine in Chrome, but they do not work in Safari when inside an Angular component (Angular 8). I can use Angular built-in animations, but I want to know what's up with CSS ones.

Thanks.

Comment: What animation in particular is not working for you in Safari?

Comment: Try to add a critical piece of your code, so that it is easier for people to answer your question